# socket.io transport error with websocket transport

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to set up a `socket.io` connection, but the connection keeps closing with a `transport error` message. Both, client and server, are running socket.io v2.0.3.

**Client**

```
var _socket = io({
  transports: ['websocket'],
  query: {
    token: userToken,
    roomName: getRoomName(),
  },
});
```

messages:

```
socket.io-client:manager attempting reconnect +5s
socket.io.min.js:1 socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +0ms
socket.io.min.js:1 socket.io-client:manager opening https://video.twoseven.xyz +1ms
socket.io.min.js:1 engine.io-client:socket creating transport "websocket" +1ms
socket.io.min.js:1 engine.io-client:socket setting transport websocket +1ms
socket.io.min.js:1 socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +2ms
socket.io.min.js:2 WebSocket connection to 'wss://video.twoseven.xyz/socket.io/?token=abcd&roomName=us&EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Invalid frame header
    r.doOpen @ socket.io.min.js:2
    r.open @ socket.io.min.js:2
    r.open @ socket.io.min.js:1
    r @ socket.io.min.js:1
    r @ socket.io.min.js:1
    r.open.r.connect @ socket.io.min.js:1
    (anonymous) @ socket.io.min.js:1
socket.io.min.js:1 engine.io-client:socket socket error {"type":"TransportError","description":{"isTrusted":true}} +733ms
socket.io.min.js:1 socket.io-client:manager connect_error +1ms
socket.io.min.js:1 socket.io-client:manager cleanup +0ms
socket.io.min.js:1 socket.io-client:manager reconnect attempt error +1ms
socket.io.min.js:1 socket.io-client:manager will wait 4769ms before reconnect attempt +1ms
socket.io.min.js:1 engine.io-client:socket socket close with reason: "transport error" +0ms
```

The Chrome developer console reports the following from the network tab:

```
General
    Request URL:wss://video.twoseven.xyz/socket.io/?token=abcd&roomName=us&EIO=3&transport=websocket
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:101 Switching Protocols
Response Headers
    Connection:upgrade
    Date:Thu, 19 Oct 2017 22:36:52 GMT
    Sec-WebSocket-Accept:YJ3aZ2L+X+ANa1bJK3ECO/s7XVE=
    Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate
    Server:nginx/1.11.8
    Upgrade:websocket
```

**Server**

```
const io = new socketio(server, {pingInterval: 3000, pingTimeout: 10000});
io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
```

messages:

```
engine handshaking client "yrFJADAHt-QQZsX6AAAA" +0ms
engine:socket sending packet "open" ({"sid":"yrFJADAHt-QQZsX6AAAA","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":3000,"pingTimeout":10000}) +3ms
engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +1ms
engine:ws writing "0{"sid":"yrFJADAHt-QQZsX6AAAA","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":3000,"pingTimeout":10000}" +1ms
engine:transport setting request +1ms
engine:socket sending packet "message" (0) +9ms
engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +19ms
engine:ws writing "40" +1ms
engine:socket sending packet "message" (2["authenticated"]) +91ms
engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
engine:ws writing "42["authenticated"]" +1ms
engine:socket transport error +136ms
engine:ws closing +2ms
```

From the server logs, I see that the `connection` event has been triggered and executes fine except for the last line which says `socket.emit('authenticated');`. The transport seems to fail at this point

Comment: Any leads on this?